# NgStyle doesn't apply with condition?

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-style

Can anyone tell my this works

```
[style.height]="events?.length === 0 ? 'calc(100vh - 105px)' : null"
```

but this doesn't?

```
[ngStyle]="{'height: calc(100vh - 105px)': events?.length === 0 }"
```

or this?

```
[style.height]="{'calc(100vh - 105px)': events?.length === 0 }"
```

Comment: wrong syntax. Try `[ngStyle]="{'height' : events?.length === 0 ? 'calc(100vh - 105px)' : null }"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle), you need to put the style attribute with values as `json` data. On that `json` data, the key should `style` name and the value should be the css attribute value as follows.

```
[ngStyle] = "{ 'height': events?.length === 0 ? 'calc(100vh - 105px)' : null }"
```

But on your code,

```
[ngStyle]="{'height: calc(100vh - 105px)': events?.length === 0 }"
```

You have put the full `[style name]: [style value]` as the key on `json` data and it won't work on `ngStyle`.

And `[style.height]` indicates the `height` css attribute on `style` html attribute.
So `[style.height]="'100px'"` has the same meaning with `style="height: 100px;"`.

And on this code,

```
[style.height]="{'calc(100vh - 105px)': events?.length === 0 }"
```

You have put `json` object into `style.height` and this is not acceptable as `height` css attribute value so it's not working.

Comment: I'm trying to find a simpler solution (without ternary operator) Trying the other examples but not having any luck. Is there any way to do it without the ternary?

Comment: You can use [ngClass] instead. Make a class named ".abc { height: calc(100vh - 105px); } and use as follows. `[ngClass]="{ 'abc': events.length === 0 }"`

Comment: I already have a ngClass like this [ngClass]="StyleLeftCol" with some variable

Comment: Or you can make variable named `additionalStyles` on controller and add additional styles due to events to that value. And can set `[style]="additionalStyles"` on template. @user1186050

Comment: I created this and I think it's prob the best for me. [ngClass]="{ StyleLeftCol: true, 'full-height': events?.length === 0}"

Comment: But wondering if there is a way to minimize 'StyleLeftCol: true'

Comment: You can directly put it into `class="StyleLeftCol" [ngClass]="{ 'full-height': events?.length === 0 }"`